# Faulting application name: csc.exe

Tags: sharepoint-server, search, error, 2016, exception

I have the following SharePoint Farm:

[image]

I noticed the CPU of the Search-Server runs costantly at 100% so I checked the Application Event-Viewer:

[image]

Each entry is an `Application Error`:

```
Faulting application name: csc.exe, version: 4.6.1087.0, time stamp: 0x583e63ba
Faulting module name: KERNELBASE.dll, version: 6.3.9600.18790, time stamp: 0x598d24e0
Exception code: 0xc0000142
Fault offset: 0x00000000000ece60
Faulting process id: 0x1eb4
Faulting application start time: 0x01d345aea03350a1
Faulting application path: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\csc.exe
Faulting module path: KERNELBASE.dll
Report Id: dddfdc75-b1a1-11e7-80cf-00155df8426b
Faulting package full name: 
Faulting package-relative application ID:
```

What exactly does this error mean? How do I fix it?

EDIT:

I observed the errors and the CPU load. The load does not rise at each error, so I suppose they are not related.

Comment: `csc` is the c-sharp compiler process.

Comment: I know, and I'm wondering what it is trying to do...

Answer (score 0):

There will be multiple errors related to this, But main thing is your server is running out of resources which is root cause of this crash (trying to load some dll which failed). if you check other events you will get that information.

As you mentioned CPU on the server 100%, i think that is the root cause. Now you have to check which process is consuming the CPU on the server.

Comment: I updated the question.

Answer (score 0):

After watching the error log I noticed the error is logged in a regular interval, in my case almost every 5 minutes. This leads me to guess the problem must be a SharePoint Job which is run every 5 minutes.

In the SharePoint `Central Administration` there are the list of the jobdefinitions:

```
http://myPortal:8005/_admin/ServiceJobDefinitions.aspx
```

They are defined to run *Weekly*, *Daily*, *Hourly*, *Minutes* or *One-Time*. I checked all the Minutes one and there are only a few run every 5 min, took one after one, changed the run time minutes and watched the log entry time. In my case it figured out the problem is the `Workflow`-Job and I think I have to look for the *faluty* `Workflow`.

I hope this (own) answer will help other people too.